# C++ sort and associate the elements with their orders in the sorted list/map

Tags: c++, sorting

I have some key value pairs that I fetched from a database to C++. I am considering storing them in a map container and use sort() to sort them. I need the order of each pair (No.1, No.10, etc) . I just realized that sort() will just return a vector in a DESC/ASC order but won't give me the specific order of each element. How should I write the program to get the orders of the elements? Thank you

INPUT

[image: Input]

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: elements in a map are already sorted based on the value of the key

Comment: Thank you but I want it to be sorted by the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you store all of the data in a struct and store the struct in a vector and then you can write custom compare functions for how you want to sort the data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct data
{
    int id;
    int value;
};

struct 
{
    bool operator()(const data & lhs, const data & rhs) { return lhs.id < rhs.id; }
} CompareId;

struct 
{
    bool operator()(const data & lhs, const data & rhs) { return lhs.value < rhs.value; }
} CompareValue;

int main()
{
    std::vector<data> database{ { 1,5 },{ 2,10 },{ 3,5 },{ 4,8 },{ 5,3 } };
    std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), CompareValue);
    for (const auto & e : database)
        std::cout << e.id << "\t" << e.value << std::endl;
    std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), CompareId);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (const auto & e : database)
        std::cout << e.id << "\t" << e.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5   3
1   5
3   5
4   8
2   10

1   5
2   10
3   5
4   8
5   3
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96b4dc7b7bdca44a)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The `map` always sort the `pair` automatically. Maybe you should use `unordered_map` for your question, it won't sort the `pairs`. So you want to sort by the value, you can store the `pairs` in ordered_map, and then sort them by yourself. It will have more high efficiency for your question. The details click here, [answer what you want](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/). I hope this can help you.

Comment: Sorry I think I confused you. I wanted to associate an element with its order in the sorted sequence. For example input {10,12,7,8}, I want to get a value-order pair like {10,3}, {12,4}, {7,1}, {8,2} where the second element of each pair is the order or the value in original vector.

Comment: @daydayup, sorry, I do not know your intention. what you want to do is keeping the origin order? For example, you put the `{10,3}, {12,4}, {7,1}` to  a `map`, you want to the order is: `{10,3}, {12,4}, {7,1}`. Is it OK?